# Morituri error ripping the last track of any CD

Tags: cd

I'm trying to rip an CD with Morituri but cannot finish the rip, gives me an error:

```
ERROR [24545] "rip" rip sep 05 10:29:16   
Giving up on track 17 after 5 times (morituri/rip/cd.py:318)
Giving up on track 17 after 5 times  `
```

The command I used is `rip cd rip --offset 667`
The CD contains 17 tracks, and several CDs I tested, all gives error ripping the last one (of course is not a CD problem itself).

Comment: It may be a "problem" with the CDs after all. A problem called "copy protection".

Comment: @CelticWarrior how can you help me with that? Ripping with `abcde` program no error appears.

Comment: @rootsanculture I can't and probably nobody else can. Errors ripping the last track are typical of copy protection. If a given software can break it doesn't mean all can.