# Noob Question - How to a make a patch work

Tags: patch

I'm facing problems for ripping Audio CD, and found a patch in a forum than maybe fixes it. But don't know to apply it.

[cdparanoia patch](http://pastebin.com/Zvj0JBEp)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would have to download the source code for cdparanoia, install any necessary libraries required for compilation, apply the patch to the source code, and compile it into a binary. This is over the heads of most beginners; maybe you could try posting your issue with ripping CDs as a question on this site to see if there's a simpler answer.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I already posted the problem days ago, but I get no responses: http://askubuntu.com/questions/821280/morituri-error-ripping-the-last-track-of-any-cd
     I'm following this instructions and want to test if works: https://github.com/thomasvs/morituri/issues/36

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the source of `cdparanoia` and apply the patch to `cdparanoia.1` file.

I've tried to use the patch and I think it was failing for an absence of newline at the end. I added one and the patch was successful. Get the modified patch from [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/AnwarShah/560d77f7d7da52553f918f3ecb7401e3)

[cdparanoia](https://www.xiph.org/paranoia/down.html) uses svn. So, if your patch file is saved as `changes.patch` and you're in a directory where `cdparanoia.1` file resides, you'll do

```
patch -p0 < changes.patch
```

- [How to make and apply SVN patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333712/how-to-make-and-apply-svn-patch)

After applying the patch, you need to compile the whole software. There is a `README` file instructing the process. Basically it is executing these commands sequentially

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: What did I wrong? That command should be applied to the sorce extracted folder? I downloaded `cdparanoia-III-10.2.src.tgz`
http://pastebin.com/fe0CDZm5

Comment: Where did you downloaded it?

Comment: @rootsandculture Some patches work differently. I saw that cdparanoia use svn. to patch it, you'll do `patch -p0 < changes.patch`

Comment: I'm completely lost :(
I readed the link How to make and apply SVN patch but I can't figure out. Could someone patch it and upload the patched file?
:)
http://pastebin.com/JRQZ4Z7T

Comment: @rootsandculture I got the same result. Make sure you found the patch file genuine and good.

Comment: @rootsandculture I think, I'll try another time.

Comment: @rootsandculture I've fixed the patch according to the instruction of [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/what-does-patch-unexpectedly-ends-in-middle-of-line-mean). Get it here. http://pastebin.com/GV1mxQQW

Comment: What should I do with that?

Comment: Patch the source code again. make sure it's not patched already. extract from the download archive

Comment: I deleted the original folder and extracted the .tgz again and moved your patched file onto that folder. I get this:
http://pastebin.com/h1fFV882

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45109/discussion-between-rootsandculture-and-anwar).